# How to check if the previous and next records are sequential in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel Spreadsheet of values. I am trying to build a string of values which will look at all the records in the sheet and determine which ones are the same (based on a sequence).. 
[image]

As you can see by the picture, there are three columns (E, F, G) which contain the source data. (source ID, target ID and Connection ID).. essentially there can only be one combination of source to target relationships, so I will need to merge any duplicate connections.

so far I have managed to find when they are duplicates by:
concatenating the source and target (Col H)
looking for duplicates (and ordering them) using the formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H:H,H2)>1,COUNTIF(H$2:H2,H2),1)
```

and Now I am trying to build a string which will be used to merge the records.

Essentially I am trying to build a function which looks for all exact strings in Col H, and then looks at the sequence(I) and builds a string like so:

34~62~65 (which tells me that connection 34 must merge with 62 and then 65)
Problem is that I have not managed to do this. 
current formula in Col J is:

```
=IF(H2=H3,IF(I3=I2+1,G3&"~"&G2,""))
```

but as you can see its only pairwise, not actually looking for the duplicates in sequence (i.e. 1 then 2 then 3 etc)

Comment: Is the inputted data actually sorted like you have it or is that after the fact sorting done by excel?  Also is the Connection value unique by chance?

Comment: There are fairly simple VBA solutions.  Can you use just a two column result of just ID and the list of connections joined by tildes?

Comment: Connection value is unique, and yes, it's a custom sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago I wrote a quite an extensive UDF for a friend of mine to deal with this problem. It is supposed to look exactly like a VLookup, except for an additional parameter UniqueOnly and a Separator.

What it does is it looks up a value based on a different cell just like VLookup, but unlike Vlookup it returns all possible values as a result, not just one.

It is used like this:

**=LookupConcatenate(LookupValue,LookupRange,LookupColumn, [Optional UniqueOnly = 0], [Optional Separator = ", "])**

And the code is:

```
Public Function LookupConcatenate(LookupValue As Range, LookupRange As Range, Column As Integer, Optional UniqueOnly As Boolean = False, Optional Separator As String = ", ") As String
' by Marek Stejskal

    Dim rngMatch As Range
    Dim rngLookup As Range
    Dim varMatch As Variant
    Dim varIndex As Variant
    Dim intFoundAll As Integer
    Dim strFoundAll() As String
    Dim intFoundUnique As Integer
    Dim strFoundUnique() As String
    Dim blnFound As Boolean
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

    Set rngLookup = LookupRange
    Set rngMatch = rngLookup.Columns(1)

    Do While 1 = 1
        ' Match function
            varMatch = Application.Match(LookupValue, rngMatch, 0)

        ' Exit checking if MATCH returned no value
            If IsError(varMatch) Then Exit Do

        ' Index function
            varIndex = Application.Index(rngLookup, varMatch, Column)
            intFoundAll = intFoundAll + 1

        ' Adding space to ALL array
            ReDim Preserve strFoundAll(1 To intFoundAll)

        ' Checking if the new result is in ALL array
            blnFound = False

            For i = 1 To UBound(strFoundAll)
                If strFoundAll(i) = CStr(varIndex) Then
                    blnFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

        ' If new result is unique add it to UNIQUE array
            If blnFound = False Then
                intFoundUnique = intFoundUnique + 1
                ReDim Preserve strFoundUnique(1 To intFoundUnique)
                strFoundUnique(intFoundUnique) = CStr(varIndex)
            End If

        ' Add the new result to ALL array
            strFoundAll(intFoundAll) = CStr(varIndex)

        ' Shortening ranges
            Set rngLookup = rngLookup.Resize(rngLookup.Rows.Count - varMatch).Offset(varMatch)
            Set rngMatch = rngLookup.Columns(1)
    Loop

    ' Creating result string
        If UniqueOnly = True Then
            If intFoundUnique = 0 Then
                strResult = ""
            Else
                For i = 1 To UBound(strFoundUnique)
                    strResult = strResult & IIf(strResult = "", "", Separator) & strFoundUnique(i)
                Next i
            End If
        Else
            If intFoundAll = 0 Then
                strResult = ""
            Else
                For i = 1 To UBound(strFoundAll)
                    strResult = strResult & IIf(strResult = "", "", Separator) & strFoundAll(i)
                Next i
            End If
        End If

    LookupConcatenate = strResult

    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    LookupConcatenate = Err.Description

End Function
```

To make this work for you, you will first need to switch the order of `Connection` and `ID` and then you can put on row 2 the formula like this:

**=LookupConcatenate(G2, G2:J100, 2, 0, "~")**

Comment: Both solutions worked like a charm.  however, I am flagging this as the answer since it gives the result exactally as I needed, (all i did was added a condtion to return nothing if there were no tilde's in the strResult.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to do this without VBA, the only way is to build the string as you go down each row.  What I mean is the final data would look like:

[image]

This does not meet the full requirements of all of column "F" containing the full concatenated string.  But the last unique row of ID would contain the final string.

The formula to put in column F (assuming your data is aligned as in the picture here)

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($D2,INDIRECT("D1:D"&ROW()-1),0)),""&$C2,IFERROR(INDEX(F:F,MATCH($D2,INDIRECT("D1:D"&ROW()-1),1)),INDEX(F:F,MATCH($D2,INDIRECT("D1:D"&ROW()-1),0)))&"~"&$C2)
```

This works even if the rows are not sorted, (and it actually does not use the sequence column at all).  Here is a picture with additional rows added as test data:

[image]

You actually then could create the column you are searching for, by adding a column containing:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($F:$F,SUBSTITUTE($F2,"~","*")&"*")=1,$F2,FALSE)
```

That would give the following final result:

[image]